# php echo a hyperlink with javascript confirm function

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have been using this code for deleting data from database. What i wan is whenever a user clicks an image link to delete data from the confirm function prompts up and ask for action, i am getting error in this code.

```
$delurl = "delete_dish.php?dish_id=".$row['id'];
$img = "<img src = 'images/delete.png'>";
echo "<a href=".$delurl.";
echo "onclick='return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete.')'>".$img."</a>";
```

Maybe the error is in double quotes or single quotes, Any help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

change

```
echo "<a href=".$delurl.";
```

to

```
echo "<a href=\"".$delurl."\" ";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$delurl = "delete_dish.php?dish_id=".$row['id'];
$img = "<img src = 'images/delete.png'>";

$confirm_box <<<CONFIRM
<a href="$delurl" 
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">$img</a> 
CONFIRM;

// then elsewhere ...
echo $confirm_box
```

Always tend towards using the [HEREDOC syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to construct HTML/JS output, it will save you a lot of heartache. Just watch out for the major gotcha, DO NOT INDENT THE FIRST/LAST lines of the heredoc declaration.

**EDIT** The benefit being that you can mix single and double quotes as much as you like, you only have to worry about the JS quoting - PHP variables are interpolated without the quotes. You can further wrap curly quotes around your PHP variables like {$this} to make it easier to read, but also to delineate $this and {$this}tle.

Answer (score 0):

I would us the following instead of escaping, this is more readable to me:

```
 $delurl = "delete_dish.php?dish_id=".$row['id'];
 $img = "<img src = 'images/delete.png'>";
?>
<a href="<?=$delurl?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"><?=$img?></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can, may and should escape when handling stuff like this:

```
echo "<a href=\".$delurl.\"";
echo " onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete.')\">".$img."</a>";
```

lg,

flo